# Can Linux C++ application connect to a remote windows DCOM API?

Tags: c++, linux, dcom

I am working on a linux c++ application. Part of it's functionality is to communicate with a 3rd party product running on windows that is exposed via a DCOM API.

Is there a stable solution that will allow me to remotely access the DCOM API from the linux machine?

thanks,

Amir.

Comment: yes, I saw that, but I can't tell if it's up-to-date or accurate. Also, I can't determine if the described solution (EntireX DCOM) does actually connect to existing 3rd party DCOM application.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model#Alternative_versions_and_implementations

But I would suggest implementing a go-between in Windows